# Loading mobilenet_v2 from hub conf gives error: cannot import name 'resnext50_32x4d'

Tags: pytorch, mobilenet

```
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.5.0', 'mobilenet_v2', pretrained=True)
```

Importing the mobile net gives an error because its dependency 'resnext50_32x4d' cannot be imported. Is this the only way to use the mobile network in torch or how can I make it work anyhow?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What Pytorch version are you using? The code you provided works for `Pytorch 1.4.0`.

Comment: @sebastian-sz thank you for your reply. I have 1.4.0 but the error still persists.